# Callbacks not called in pyosmium's diff downloader

Tags: osmium

For some reason, this code does not print any nodes, ways, or relations, even though it clearly does download the minute updates from OpenStreetMap:

```
import logging
import osmium
from osmium.replication.server import ReplicationServer

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class Handler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Handler, self).__init__()

    def node(self, n):
        print('n', n.id)

    def way(self, w):
        print('w', w.id)

    def relation(self, r):
        print('r', r.id)

h = Handler()
rs = ReplicationServer('http://planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/minute')
rs.apply_diffs(h, 2112110, 0.4*1024)
```

Result:

```
$ python3 osm2rdf.py
DEBUG:pyosmium:Downloaded change 2112110. (86 kB available in download buffer)
DEBUG:pyosmium:Downloaded change 2112111. (36 kB available in download buffer)
DEBUG:pyosmium:Downloaded change 2112112. (4 kB available in download buffer)
DEBUG:pyosmium:Downloaded change 2112113. (-139 kB available in download buffer)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note that there hasn't been a single 'n', 'w', or 'r' printed after change downloading.

Comment: See https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium/issues/38

Comment: @mmd, thanks, I was the one who created both, thinking that it might be my bug.  Turns out it wasn't :)  Glad it got resolved so fast!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug in the pyosmium itself. Closing.